# SQL to compare field values within a set of rows grouped by a unique ID per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The objective is to query on name changes within an audit table. I only want to select rows that contain a name change.

For each record update, 2 rows are created – a before update and an after update. 
[image]

I want to compare the values in `KEYNAME` per unique `auditkey`. 
So, I'd like to group these 2 top records by the unique `auditkey` on rows 80 & 81. Then I'd like to compare the values in rows 80 and 81. I'd only like to select the second row (afterupdate) IF the values are different.

I am using SQL server 2008.

I'm thinking I Can do something like:

```
select distinct AUDITKEY, KEYNAME 
from dbo.CONSTITUENTAUDIT
```

into a temp table, then run a count on the auditkey column within the temp table. Anything that has a count > 1 is what i'm looking for.

Comment: You should blank out those KeyNames if they are real.

Comment: Where does AUDITTYPE come from?

Comment: Thanks cronos - I'll do that now. AUDITTYPE is automatically added every time there's an update to the record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`JOIN`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490(v=sql.105).aspx) a table to itself (a self-join). So just extract records that have `AUDITTYPE = 1` (after update) with a different `KEYNAME` than the record with the same `AUDITKEY` but with `AUDITTYPE = 0`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8b47/3)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([AUDITKEY] varchar(36), [AUDITTYPE] int, [AUDITTYPECODE] varchar(13), [KEYNAME] varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([AUDITKEY], [AUDITTYPE], [AUDITTYPECODE], [KEYNAME])
VALUES
    ('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012', 0, 'before update', 'BLABLABLA'),
    ('12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012', 1, 'after update', 'BLABLABLA'),
    ('22345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012', 0, 'before update', 'BLABLA'),
    ('22345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012', 1, 'after update', 'ALBALB')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT T2.AUDITKEY, T2.KEYNAME
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table1 T2 ON T1.AUDITKEY = T2.AUDITKEY AND
                        T1.AUDITTYPE = 0 AND T2.AUDITTYPE = 1 AND
                        T1.KEYNAME <> T2.KEYNAME
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8b47/3/0)**:

```
|                             AUDITKEY | KEYNAME |
|--------------------------------------|---------|
| 22345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012 |  ALBALB |
```

Comment: This worked! My thinking was flawed - I was going to use a temporary table but that was an extra step. Self joins from now on. THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can join table on itself:

```
SELECT a.* FROM dbo.CONSTITUENTAUDIT a
JOIN dbo.CONSTITUENTAUDIT b 
    ON a.AUDITKEY = b.AUDITKEY and a.AUDITTYPE <> b.AUDITTYPE 
        and a.AUDITTYPE = 'AFTER UPDATE' and a.KEYNAME <> b.KEYNAME
```

it should work the way you ask it.